# Merging xml elements with nokogiri

Tags: nokogiri

I am trying to get the content of an XML::Element type. I have tried the content method, but that gives me the text and I am
not just interested in the text.

The XML element I have has tags, and I don't want to lose that information. For example, Suppose XML::Element myElement has:

```
<block>
  element has other tags like <tag> ... </tag>
  <a href ... > </a> ...
  <blah> </blah>
  etc..  
</block>
```

So I want a method that will return:

```
element has other tags like <tag> ... </tag>
<a href ... > </a> ...
<blah> </blah>
etc..
```

Ultimately, I want to use this to actually merge XML elements into
one. If there exists such method already let me know or if you have
a nice approach to merge them effectively. As an example,

I have two blocks

```
<block>
  block 1 has tags like <tag> ... </tag>
  <a href ... > </a> ...
  <blah> </blah>
  etc..  
</block>
<block>
  block 2 has tags like <tag> ... </tag>
  <a href ... > </a> ...
  <blah> </blah>
  etc..  
</block>
```

and would want to have it all in one block as follows:

```
<block>
  block 1 has tags like <tag> ... </tag>
  <a href ... > </a> ...
  <blah> </blah>
  etc..  
  block 2 has tags like <tag> ... </tag>
  <a href ... > </a> ...
  <blah> </blah>
  etc..  
</block>
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah just realized how to get the information inside a two tags

puts xmlelement.inner_html